# how do i block or restrict special characters from input fields with javascript

Tags: javascript

```
Yazi&nbsp;<input type="text" id="yazi" value="">
<button onclick="ElaveEt();">OK</button>

<div id="list"></div>
<script>
    function ElaveEt() {
        if (document.getElementById("yazi").value.c.length > null) {
            objYazi = document.getElementById("yazi");
            objList = document.getElementById("list");

            objList.innerHTML = objList.innerHTML  + '<div id="Step">'+ objYazi.value + '<button  onclick="YaziniSil();" >Sil</button>' + '<div>';
            //document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = document.getElementById("list").innerHTML + '<br>' + document.getElementById("yazi").value;
            document.getElementById("yazi").value = null;

        } else {
            alert('Boş xana əlavə oluna bilməz!')
        }
    }
    function YaziniSil() {
        document.getElementById("Step").remove();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: `Element.value.match()`. Learn Regular Expressions.

Comment: You do not have to add the code in your code. I just have to block the characters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to authorize only alpha numerique on your input this is my suggestion :

```
<input type="text" id="yazi" value=""  onkeypress="return alpha(event)"/>
    <button onclick="ElaveEt();">OK</button>

    <div id="list"></div>
    </div>
        <script>
            function ElaveEt() {
                if (document.getElementById("yazi").value.length > 0) {
                    objYazi = document.getElementById("yazi");
                    objList = document.getElementById("list");

                    objList.innerHTML = objList.innerHTML  + '<div id="Step">'+ objYazi.value + '<button  onclick="YaziniSil();" >Sil</button>' + '<div>';
                    //document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = document.getElementById("list").innerHTML + '<br>' + document.getElementById("yazi").value;
                    document.getElementById("yazi").value = null;

                } else {
                    alert('Boş xana əlavə oluna bilməz!')
                }
            }
            function YaziniSil() {
                document.getElementById("Step").remove();
            }

         function alpha(e) {
            var k;
            document.all ? k = e.keyCode : k = e.which;
            return ((k > 64 && k < 91) || (k > 96 && k < 123) || k == 8 || k == 32 || (k >= 48 && k <= 57));
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: thank you very much. But let me not only allow the characters to enter

Comment: I just **edit** the code can you check the new version please `<input type="text" id="yazi" value=""  onkeypress="return alpha(event)"/>`

Comment: Thank you very much for this job. But this user may not be welcome. Is there anything you can do to include characters but not to remember?

Comment: I'm sorry but I didn't understand your question. Can you give an example or more clarification ?

Comment: I want to include the character, but do not keep this character in mind when I click the Arrow button